# Ruby form_for explanation?

Tags: ruby, form-for

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two? I seem to get the same result

```
<%= form_for (@message) do |f| %>
```

vs

```
<%= form_for Message.new, remote: true do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remote: true` is used to make the form submit happen via AJAX.

More info about this is available in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for) (Courtesy Arup)

The other difference lies in the object `@message`. If it was initialized using existing data from the database, the form generated will come pre-filled

eg, If in the controller code is

```
@message = Message.new
```

Then the output of the two forms will be identical, but if the controller code is

```
@message = Message.find(params[:id])
```

then the form will be filled with values of `@message`

Comment: +1 Link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for in your answer too, if you want

Comment: Thank you now I understand it completely!